# How to send parameter from anchor click event in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to send parameter to click event from anchor element, is it possible of we should not pass params at all?

here is my function:

```
 const slideShow = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement> | undefined): void => {
        console.log(e);
    }
```

html :

```
<div className="slider">
  <a className="prev" onClick={slideShow}>Previous</a>
    <h2>Barking Road, London</h2>
    <a className="next" onClick={slideShow}>Next</a>
</div>
```

but when user click on `prev` link i would like to send `-1` and for the `next` with `1` as parameter. is there any way? or totally it's not applicable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. use data-* attribute

```
const slideShow = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement> | undefined): void => {
  console.log(e.currentTarget.dataset.step);
  // do something with step parameter
}


<div className="slider">
  <a data-step={-1} className="prev" onClick={slideShow}>Previous</a>
  <h2>Barking Road, London</h2>
  <a data-step={1} className="next" onClick={slideShow}>Next</a>
</div>
```

2. nested function

```
const slideShow = (step: number) => (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement> | undefined): void => {
  console.log(step);
  // do something with step parameter
}

// above function is like:
const slideShow = (step: number) => {
  return (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement> | undefined): void => {
    console.log(step);
    // do something with step parameter
  }
}


<div className="slider">
  <a className="prev" onClick={slideShow(-1)}>Previous</a>
  <h2>Barking Road, London</h2>
  <a className="next" onClick={slideShow(1)}>Next</a>
</div>
```

3. arrow function

```
const slideShow = (step: number): void => {
  console.log(step);
  // do something with step parameter
}


<div className="slider">
  <a className="prev" onClick={() => slideShow(-1)}>Previous</a>
  <h2>Barking Road, London</h2>
  <a className="next" onClick={() => slideShow(1)}>Next</a>
</div>
```

Comment: can  you help here, my slide not updating on prev and next click : https://codesandbox.io/s/great-noether-dz66q?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use a `state` for your aim:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(value);
  }, [value]);
  const slideShow = (
    e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement> | undefined,
    value: number
  ): void => {
    e?.preventDefault();
    setValue(value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="slider">
      <a href="/" className="prev" onClick={ (e) => slideShow(e, -1) }>
        Previous
      </a>
      <h2>Barking Road, London</h2>
      <a href="/" className="next" onClick={ (e) => slideShow(e, 1) }>
        Next
      </a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit crazy-haibt-o9tu8]

Comment: Ok, But why do we need to use `useEffect` here?

Comment: @user2024080 I used `useEffect` to show you the value which you need is updated!

Comment: @user2024080 You do not need to use the `useEffect`. It's just a sample.

Comment: Hi Majid my slide is not working: https://codesandbox.io/s/great-noether-dz66q?file=/src/App.tsx can you help me?

Comment: @user2024080 Here's the updated code: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-ives-7gfyy?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: @user2024080 Did it help?

Answer (score -1):

It is easy to send parameter to function just instead of:

```
<a className="prev" onClick={slideShow}>Previous</a>
```

use:

```
<a className="prev" onClick={(e) =>{slideShow(e, -1)}}>Previous</a>
```

having:

```
const slideShow = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement> | undefined, value:number): void => {
   console.log(e, number);
}
```